# Splinter Cell guards know everything. Possible to fix?

Tags: cheats, splinter-cell-chaos-theory

In Splinter Cell Chaos Theory, whenever you get spotted by a guard or shoot them with an airfoil round or something even up close, the same split second all guards in the area magically knows you're there. I want to fix this in any way possible. Cheats, game modification, anything, because it's starting to get on my nerves and really kills the realism.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all there are a few things that could be happening:

1. You're not in the dark. If you're not in the dark in most cases you're going to be instantly caught whenever... (read point 2)
2. You are loud. NPCs are attracted to noise. They proceed to identify what the noise was (A sticky cam, Sam walking, a rock, a bottle). Once that's done they act accordingly (some try to hide, some fire at you, some run to alarms). If Sam is the one making noise check point 1.

---

With that being  said, there's are indeed cheats, but unfortunally only for the PC version. You can read up on how to set them [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309292/what-are-all-the-cheats-in-tom-clancys-splinter-cell-chaos-theory/309293#309293).

The cheat you want to use in this case is **invisible**, which makes it so NPCs (guards) cannot see you. They can however still hear you. You can also be spotted by cameras.