# What are all the cheats in Tom Clancy's Splinter Cell: Chaos Theory

Tags: pc, splinter-cell-chaos-theory

There are only cheats for the PC version, what are they, and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cheats require you to edit the game files so it's not a bad idea to make a backup. The file you need to edit is (by default) at:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/USERNAME/Application Data/Ubisoft/Tom Clancy’s Splinter Cell Chaos Theory/profiles).
 // USERNAME = The username you have on your computer
```

Then open the game profile in which you wish to cheat on. If the in-game profile is default, then open the folder **Default**, and open **default.ini** with any text editor.

Simply scrolldown until you find the Hotkey assignment (A list with all available keys), and add one of the codes to the desired key.

Then simply use the hotkey in game (For example, you can set F12 to give you a frag grenade. Whenever you press F12 in-game it spawns a frag grenade that you can pick up)

---

**The following list details all the currently known cheat codes:**

Code - Effect

> fly - Allows you to float in the air
>
> Invisible - NPCs can no longer see you (but they can hear you). However cameras and similar security devices catch you
>
> Invincible - You become.. Invincible
>
> health - Gives health
>
> ammo - Gives ammo
>
> summon echeloningredient.eringairfoilround - spawns an airfold round
>
> summon echeloningredient.eflashgrenade - spawns a flashbang grenade
>
> summon echeloningredient.efraggrenade - spawns a frag grenade
>
> summon echeloningredient.esmokegrenade - spawns a smoke grenade
>
> summon echeloningredient.estickycamera - spawns a Sticky Cam
>
> summon echeloningredient.estickyshocker - spawns a Sticky Shocker
>
> summon echeloningredient.ewallmine - spawns a Wallmine